# update document in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch by Restclient in Firefox adds-on 
and I have the following problem when updating a document

```
{
    "error": "JsonParseException[Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
 at [Source: [B@142d626; line: 3, column: 12]]",
    "status": 500
}
```

and i do this

```
method : post
url: http://localhost:9200/test2/t2/2/_update?pretty
in body 
{    "doc" : 
    "name":"oooooo"
}
```

any help
thanks

Comment: JSON doesn't look right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following JSON in your body:

```
{   
    "doc": {
        "name": "oooooo"
    }
}
```

In order to do a [partial update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html), the JSON in the body must have a single `doc` field which contains the fields to update, in this case `"name": "oooooo"`. In your case, you were simply missing the curly braces around the `name` field.

Comment: thanks for your answer
now i have this problem
"error": "DocumentMissingException[[test4][2] [t4][1]: document missing]",
    "status": 404


id do this
method : post
url :http://localhost:9200/test4/t4/1/_update?pretty

my body :
{
  "doc": { "name": "Jane Docccce" }
}

Comment: It means that you don't have any document with id = 1, are you sure this is the correct id of the document you want to update?

Comment: thank you very much 
i correct the id and update the document 
you are the best
thank you again